# Tribute to Stan Lee in The Flash?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, stan-lee

In the latest episode of The Flash, *[All Doll'd Up](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8312894/)*, we see Ralph aka Elongated Man swinging over buildings, throwing arms around like Spider Man does his web, while carrying Iris on his back. Just before that, he said he saw this in a comic book. It sounded to me like a tribute to Stan Lee. Am I right in thinking that, or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Arrowverse specially Flash is famous for referencing other property specially marvel, just a coincident with Stan Lee death, some references; https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/04/06/arrowverse-tv-the-cw-easter-eggs-marvel-mcu/#4 but sure;y not a  bad question +1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say **no**.

Stan Lee died on 12 November, and the episode premiered in the US on *13* November. There is no way they could possibly have rushed out such an indirect, CG-intensive tribute in such a short space of time.

Most likely, the episode was written months ago, the scene is a reference to Spider-Man rather than Stan Lee, and the fact it aired only a day after his death is just a tragic coincidence.

Comment: Yes, I agree the episode was written and filmed way in advance. But is it possible for the episode to have been re-scheduled or was it a complete coincidence it aired at this time?

Comment: If the show consisted of random disconnected episodes like (say) *Family Guy*, then it might be possible, but I believe *The Flash* has continuous arcs, and shuffling episodes around like that would have caused continuity errors. So again, probably not.

Comment: @vlaz: the CW usually releases the synopsis and episode titles of *The Flash* weeks in advance. We probably knew that the episode of this week was about Rag'Doll before (or shortly after) the season started. There was no episode last week because of the elections. So impossible that episodes have been switched.